Warning and ConnectionRefusedError when using hrequests package on Linux
I'm encountering issues while using the hrequests package on my Linux server. When importing the package, I frequently receive the following warning:
HTTP server ListenAndServe: listen tcp: lookup tcp/@…�Ñd: unknown port

The characters after tcp/ change with each occurrence. This warning doesn't appear every time I import the package, but it's quite frequent.
When this warning appears, I know my hrequests code will later throw an error:
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I've attempted to isolate the issue by using a Docker container, but the error persists. My Dockerfile starts with:
FROM ubuntu:24.04

Then I install Python 3.11 and hrequests.
Interestingly, everything works fine on my local Windows machine running Python 3.11, with no errors occurring.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide a Docker setup where hrequests works correctly.

So, some other piece of software misbehaves? That would be the topic for a bug ticket. For a question here, you'd have to extract a [mcve], please.
